# how to work with the service task in bpmn for wso2 bps server?

Tags: wso2, activiti, bpmn, wso2-business-process

Can anyone let me know the stepwise method of connecting a maven java class to a service task of bpmn (designed using activiti in eclipse)?

Please help me out. I am stuck now.

Answer (score 0):

You should build the maven project and copy the jar file to /repository/components/lib folder. Restart the BPS server and then deploy the .bar package with service task. Following link [1] describes a sample for this.

[1] - https://docs.wso2.com/display/BPS360/Java+Service+Task